# Create folders and upload text files to server (php) in Unity3D (C#)

Tags: c#, php, file, unity-game-engine, text

**What I have :**

I have a simple module that would convert a string to a text file & store it in my server

**C#/Unity Code**

```
private IEnumerator UploadUserData(string _fileName)
{        
    string _data = ("With text name " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString ());
    string _postDataURL = "https://nameofserver.com/upload.php"

    WWWForm _form = new WWWForm ();
    _form.AddField ("name", _fileName);
    _form.AddField ("data", _data);      

    UnityWebRequest _wwwRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post (_postDataURL, _form);

    yield return _wwwRequest.Send ();

    while (!_wwwRequest.isDone)
    {   yield return null;}

    if (_wwwRequest.error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log (_wwwRequest.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("Uploaded");
    }

    Debug.Log (_wwwRequest.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

**Server Side PHP**

```
 <?php    
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['data'])){
    file_put_contents($_POST['name'].".txt", $_POST['data']);      
    echo "uploaded.";
}else{
    echo "invalid file uploaded.";
}
```

?>

**Request**

I want to build a system where I could upload files to specific folders. Let's say I to upload a text file (filename.txt) to a folder name "Folder1".

**From php side**

- The php side should create a folder "Folder1" if it is not present
  then upload the text file "filename.txt" to that folder
- if "Folder1" exist in that directory, then I would like the php
  script to upload that text file "filename.txt" to the existing folder
  "Folder1"

**From Unity Side**

How should I mention the folder name from Unity webrequest?

Thank you very much for your time. Much appreciate it.

Comment: That folder name would, presumably, be part of the `file_put_contents` call in PHP.

Comment: @Draco18s I appreciate your comment. I totally new to php, hence could you please help me with a code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I know very little about PHP myself.

Answer (score 1):

Like I was ranting at you on IRC, you should avoid allowing your file paths to be dictated by, or even include, data supplied by a user or even a user-accessible API.

I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
// always have something define the absolute path to your application root,
// then build your paths/filenames relative to that.
// let's say this is /usr/local/myapp/config/config.php
define('APPROOT', realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')); // APPROOT == '/usr/local/myapp'
define('USERUPLOADS', APPROOT . '/user_uploads');

// userid SHOULD be something you control, not a username or anything specified
// by the user. the focus is to prevent malformed and/or malevolent user data
// from breaking out of the upload directory sandbox.
function acceptUploadedUserData($userid, $name, $data) {
    $userdir = USERUPLOADS . '/' . $userid;
    if( ! is_dir($userdir) ) {
        mkdir($userdir);
    }
    // just kinda baseline "OK"
    if( strpos('..', $name) !== false || strpos('/', $name) !== false ) {
        throw new Exception('Specified name cannot contain .. or /');
    }
    file_put_contents($userdir . '/' . $name, $data);

    // better yet don't let the user have *any* control over any part of the path
    // but also allows you to specify *any* string as the filename.
    file_put_contents($userdir . '/' . md5($name), $data);
}

acceptUploadedUserData($_SESSION['user_id'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['data']);
```